# clickable links and images in dataframe with jupyter notebbok

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I created the following code in jupyter notebook to display clickable links and display images, but neither of them work. Both links and image links are displayed as text only.

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

def make_clickable(val):
    # target _blank to open new window
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val, val)

def show_image(val):
    return '<img src="{}>"'.format(val)

df.style.format({'link': make_clickable,'image_link': show_image})
HTML(df.to_html(escape=True))
```

Comment: Looks like there is no closing `>` for `img`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the result in `IPython.display.HTML`?

Comment: yes, I've tried: HTML(df.to_html(escape=True)). There's no change. I've updated the original code.